# While loop of a string containing at least six words in C#

Tags: c#, validation, c#-4.0, c#-3.0, c#-2.0

I am attempting to code a while loop validation to validate the user's response whenever they entered a sentence with the following criteria:

- The string is null or empty
- Sentence must be at least six words.

I was able to able to get the the null or empty condition to work as expected, but the "must be at least six words" isn't working as intended at the moment. Whenever I type a sentence with less than six words it accepts it fine. However, If i input a sentence with six words or more it prompts the established error message when it shouldn't.

```
        while (String.IsNullOrEmpty(sentence) || sentence.Length != 6)
        {
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(sentence))
            {

                Console.WriteLine("Please, do not leave the sentence field empty!");
                Console.WriteLine("Enter your desired sentence again: ");
                sentence = ReadLine();
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\r\nThe sentece entered isn't valid. Must have a least six words!");
                Console.WriteLine("Enter a sentence with a least 6 words: ");
                sentence = ReadLine();
            }
        }
```

What exactly am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
string sentence = Console.ReadLine();
        while (true)
        {
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(sentence))
            {

                Console.WriteLine("Please, do not leave the sentence field empty!");
                Console.WriteLine("Enter your desired sentence again: ");

            }
            else if (sentence.Split(' ').Length < 6)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\r\nThe sentece entered isn't valid. Must have a least six words!");
                Console.WriteLine("Enter a sentence with a least 6 words: ");
            }
            else break;
            sentence = Console.ReadLine();
        }
```

Comment: It should be <6 not <5

Answer (score 0):

Change `while (String.IsNullOrEmpty(sentence) || sentence.Length != 6)` to

```
while (String.IsNullOrEmpty(sentence) || sentence.Split(' ').Length < 6)
```

Comment: I added the line your suggested. However, it still prompts the message error when I enter a word that is six word and greater.

Comment: @NTaveras what `sentence` did you enter?

Comment: You are looking for words not for chars in string, please see my answer.

Comment: He needs to repeat the test on the splitted string, not just falling in the else block

Comment: oh okay! I see what you mean now.

Comment: @Steve, the test is repeated in the while. The string is null or Empty and the user gets prompted. When he writes a sentence less than 6 words, he gets prompted about that, else it breaks out the while

Answer (score 0):

`sentence.Length` returns the number of characters in the string. You must split the sentence into words.

```
string[] words = sentence.Split();
```

splits at white-space characters.

Therefore, you can write your loop as

```
while (String.IsNullOrEmpty(sentence) || sentence.Split().Length < 6)
{
    ...
}
```

Here `Length` is the length of string-array resulting from the split.

Note that in case the sentence is `null`, the [short-circuit evaluation](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/short-circuit-evaluation-in-c-sharp/) of Boolean expressions of C# will not execute the sub-expression following the `||`. Therefore you will not get a null-reference-exception.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly You can change you while condition like bellow...
it will give you a sentence that length less then six
     while (sentence.Length < 6)
When you want to get a word that will be six word in length then try bellow condition...

```
sentence.Split(' ').Length >= 6
```

Answer (score 0):

// At first try to change while condition like bellow ....then try bellow code..

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int count = 0;
        inputSteream:
        Console.WriteLine("Enter your  sentence: ");
        string sentence = Console.ReadLine();
        while (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(sentence) && sentence.Length >= 6)
        {
            foreach (var item in sentence.Split(' '))
            {
                if (item.Length >= 6)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("The sentece is {0}", item);
                    count++;
                    break;
                }

            }
            break;
        }
        if (count == 0)
        {
            goto inputSteream;
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

Comment: it is not the intent to downvote other peoples answer when you think, you have a better answer..

Comment: Sorry Dear Aldert .I was happen by mistake

Answer (score 0):

Try like below sample code

```
 string sentence=Console.ReadLine();

            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(sentence))
            {

                Console.WriteLine("Please, do not leave the sentence field empty!");
                Console.WriteLine("Enter your desired sentence again: ");
                sentence = Console.ReadLine();
            }
            else if(sentence.Length!=6)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\r\nThe sentece entered isn't valid. Must have a least six words!");
                Console.WriteLine("Enter a sentence with a least 6 words: ");
                sentence =  Console.ReadLine();
            }
            else
            {
            Console.WriteLine("Your entered string length is'{0}' and word is{1}", sentence.Length,sentence);
            }
```